# How do I make collision between class and class?

Tags: processing, collision

This is my code so far...
We have the main class, the eye class, the enemy class, the face class, and the message class.
So my question is how do I make a collision, or whatever I have to do for the face class and the enemy class, when they touch the game will stop.
I hope you understand! Anyone help? Appreciate it<3

```
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some leads which might be useful for you.

First you mention a `Person` class but it is not in the code you shared, so I will assume that you consider an enemy to have touched the person if it touches either the `Face` or one of the `Eye`s.

Here according to your `display()` functions for `Enemy`, `Face` and `Eye` all the objects are some circles (i.e. `ellipse()` used with the same diameter for both horizontal and vertical diameters). So are you are trying to do is to detect a collision between circles, which is pretty straightforward:

Take two circles with positions `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` and diameters `d1` and `d2`. Those circles are colliding if the distance between their position is less than the sum of their diameter `isColliding = dist((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) <= d1 + d2` (if you're not sure it's true you can take a sheet of paper and a pencil and draw circles colliding and not colliding, you should verify this property pretty quickly).

So the first thing you'll need is to write a function which will take four parameters and return a boolean like this:

```
boolean collideCircles(PVector p1, int d1, PVector p2, int d2)
```

If you are not familiar with the `PVector` class have a look at [this documentation](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html), this is a way to store your object position components `x` and `y`.

In this function you will need to calculate the distance between `p1` and `p2` which are the position of both of your circles. You can do that with the [`dist()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_dist_.html) method of the `PVector` class and you will need to compare this distance with the sum of the diameters `d1` and `d2`.

Once this function is working you can call it with the objects you need to check for collision (i.e. the 1st eye and all the enemies, the 2nd eye and all the enemies and the face and all the enemies).

Then when this function returns `true` you'll know that you can stop your game: There are a lot of different ways to do that so it will be up to you to decide which way to go. A first simple way to test is to use [`noLoop()`](https://processing.org/reference/noLoop_.html) which stops the processing loop.

---

The previous part was about the basis of what you need to create, now here are a few advises which might help you:

- Once your function `collideCircles()` is written you could write a new method to the `Face` class like this `boolean collideWithEnemies(Enemy[] enemies)` this function would take an array of enemies, it would iterate over this array and call `collideCircles()` 3 times. `p1` and `x1` will always be the current enemy and `p2`, `d2` would be successively the position and diameter of each eyes and of the face. You can then call this function from `draw()` this way at each new frame you will compute your collisions.
- As I suggested in the previous point your code would be much easier to use if you used arrays (see [the doc](https://processing.org/reference/Array.html)) you could use them to store the enemies and the `rect()` you use in `draw()` (which I assume are walls)
- In every class where you have two properties `x` and `y` you could instead use a `PVector` this is a good habit to take as it will simplify your code and you'll be able to use all the existing methods of the `PVector` class (to calculate distances, angles and lot of other stuff)
- To improve your `collideCircles` method you could create a class `CircularObject` which will have only a `PVector position` and `int diameter`. The function signature would become `boolean collideCicle(CircularObject c1, CircularObject c2)`. And then you can have your classes `Face`, `Eye` and `Enemy` inheriting from this class (see [the doc](https://processing.org/reference/extends.html)) and this way you'll be able to call `collideCircles` directly with your objects like `isColliding = collideCircles(face, enemy1)`
- The function which I described to check for collision works but is inefficient. With a few enemies and two eyes, things should works pretty seamlessly but if your project grows up you will see some slow down. There are a lot of ways to improve that. One simple way to improve the function is to know that the `PVector` `dist()` method uses a squared root calculation (because of the formula for the distance between two points, which involves a square root) and this is costly. To avoid this square root calculation you could directly calculate the squared distance between the circles (`sqrdDist = (p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y)`) and check against the squared sum of the diameters of the circles. If you need something even more efficient you'll need to use specific data structures like [Quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), but that is not as trivial to use as the method I described before.
- Finally your code is badly formatted and that makes it pretty hard to read (your indentations are not consistent, you have a lot of useless empty lines, etc) the IDE or the text editor you are using probably has an auto-formatting feature you should use it you will feel much more comfortable writing and reading your code after that.

One last point: Collision detection in processing is something fairly common and there are a log of resources online you should check [here](https://processing.org/examples/circlecollision.html) is an example with circles collisions and some additional physics to bounce the balls, [the coding train](https://www.youtube.com/c/TheCodingTrain/) youtube channel has a lot of amazing material about collision and a good search engine should return thousands of relevant material too.

Comment: I really appreciate that, honestly!!! I will try to add all those things and we will see. Thanks a lottt!!<3 and thanks for explaining everything!

Comment: No problem, if you feel like this answers you question you can also mark it as approved with the green check button just under the downvote button :)

Comment: hi sorry to ask again but I do not understand where to put these things. :( like in the beginning, in a method and I am confused. I am so sorry! if you can please enlighten me? appreciate it<3

Comment: You need to start small if you don't know how to architecture your code start with one character and a few walls, make them collide, then work up with more objects. Then in the process you'll find precise problems which you can ask about on SO but asking such a broad question will not give you useful information.